# Difference between Google Maps Place API & Google Maps Time Zone API

Tags: google-maps, google-api, geolocation, timezone, google-places-api

Why Google Maps Timezone Web Service works with/without specifying API-KEY but Google Places Web Service needs API-KEY?
Generally why some google web services don't insist on entering API-KEY, do they monitor IP?

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know Google intends to deprecate a keyless access to their APIs. The last one was keyless access deprecation for Maps JavaScript API, Static Maps API and Street View API announced on June 22, 2016.

https://maps-apis.googleblog.com/2016/06/building-for-scale-updates-to-google.html

Probably, keyless access for web services will be deprecated at some point as well.

Currently, if you execute TimeZone API with an API key your quota is applied on per project basis. Otherwise the quota is applied on per IP basis. If you share the IP with somebody else probably you couldn't execute 2500 daily requests. So, an API key is a better option to control your usage.

#### Update

With migration to [Google Maps Platform](https://mapsplatform.googleblog.com/2018/05/introducing-google-maps-platform.html) that was announced on May 2, 2018 the keyless access was deprecated for all APIs. From now on you must use an API key and enable Billing account in your project in order to be able to use Google Maps APIs.